# How to find the number of unique values in comma separated strings stored in an pandas data frame column?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, apply

| x | Unique_in_x |
| --- | --- |
| 5,5,6,7,8,6,8 | 4 |
| 5,9,8,0 | 4 |
| 5,9,8,0 | 4 |
| 3,2 | 2 |
| 5,5,6,7,8,6,8 | 4 |

Unique_in_x is my expected column.Sometime x column might be string also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with a `set`

```
df['Unique_in_x'] = [len(set(x.split(','))) for x in df['x']]
```

Or using a [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Dataframe.nunique.html):

```
df['Unique_in_x'] = df['x'].str.split(',', expand=True).nunique(1)
```

Output:

```
               x  Unique_in_x
0  5,5,6,7,8,6,8            4
1        5,9,8,0            4
2        5,9,8,0            4
3            3,2            2
4  5,5,6,7,8,6,8            4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the unique value of the list with `np.unique()` and then just use the length

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['Unique_in_x'] = df['X'].apply(lambda x : len(np.unique(x.split(','))))
```

Comment: There is also a `nunique` method to directly count the number of uniques ;)

Comment: So instead of ‘len(np.unique(list))’ it would be ‘np.nunique(list)’ ?

Comment: I wouldn't use `apply` here, check my answer. But the fastest remains the list comprehension